# INSERT error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am working with oracle (with Toad) but when I try to execute this query

```
INSERT INTO KEYUSER(NAME) VALUES(UNAME) WHERE ID = 1;
```

I get this error:

> SQL command not properly ended. Found 'WHERE' expecting ;-or- LOG -or- RETURN RETURNING

What is wrong? Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **never** use where clause in insert statement. It does not make any sense to have it while you are simply trying to insert a row.

Answer (score 1):

General  Insert statement is like below

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

So in your case you have to remove `where` clause from your statement and query will be like below

```
INSERT INTO KEYUSER(NAME) VALUES('UNAME');
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you intend an `UPDATE` rather than `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE KEYUSER
    SET NAME = UNAME
    WHERE ID = 1;
```

Sometimes new users of SQL get confused between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.  `INSERT` inserts new *rows* into a table. `UPDATE` changes values in existing rows.  The confusion is become some people interpret `INSERT` as "inserting new values into a row".